# Ruby 2.5.1 crashed - how to read this memory map?

Tags: ruby, memory

I'm upgrading to Ruby 2.5.1 and when a unicorn worker crashed during testing, I got a ton of output that I'm not sure how to interpret.

Does anyone know what each of these columns means? I think if I understood this better, I'd be able to find what caused the issue, as the output is rather larger than what I pasted here.

```
* Process memory map:

55d388ebb000-55d3891db000 r-xp 00000000 ca:01 4623622  /opt/ruby-2.5.1/bin/ruby
55d3893db000-55d3893e0000 r--p 00320000 ca:01 4623622  /opt/ruby-2.5.1/bin/ruby
55d3893e0000-55d3893e1000 rw-p 00325000 ca:01 4623622  /opt/ruby-2.5.1/bin/ruby
55d3893e1000-55d3893f2000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
55d38b066000-55d38bdf9000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0        [heap]
55d38bdf9000-55d38d1a9000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0        [heap]
55d38d1a9000-55d3a1258000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0        [heap]
7f1bcc000000-7f1bcc021000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f1bcc021000-7f1bd0000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f1bd0e68000-7f1bd1031000 r--s 00000000 ca:01 13016                      
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.23.so
....
```